# react native : How to fix the error - Passing an inline function will cause the component state to be lost on re-render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

**I got this warning :**
"Passing an inline function will cause the component state to be lost on re-render and cause perf issues since it's re-created every render. You can pass the function as children to 'Screen' instead to achieve the desired behaviour".
I try to pass the `item` parameter to the "Neptun" component function type and then I get the above error.
How can I fix this issue ?

```
<Tab.Screen
          name="FOOD"
          component={() => <Neptun item={item} />}
          listeners={({ route }) => ({
            focus: () => {
              dispatch(
                setCurrentTabInfoAction({
                  currentTabName: route.name,
                  type: 'approved',
                })
              );
            },
          })}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
```

Comment: From where do you get `item` passed to `Neptun` ?

Comment: from the function of the Tab.Screen ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either do the following ...
Which is the suggested solution by the warning ...

> You can pass the function as children to 'Screen' instead to achieve
> the desired behaviour".

```
  return (
    <Tab.Screen
      name="FOOD"

      // component={() => <Neptun item={item} />}
    >
      {() => <Neptun item={item} />}
    </Tab.Screen>
  );
```

OR

```
<Tab.Screen name="FOOD" component={Neptun} />
```

And make `Neptun` fetch `item` from some sort of global-store like: `React Context`, or `Redux`...

Comment: Did you try the other solution?? .. and do you have redux wired in your app ?

Comment: i try the other and its works but i think it more better use redux.

Comment: You may try Const Neptun = ()=> <Neptune item={item} />;
Then user Neptun in the screen component -

<Tab.Screen
          name="FOOD"
          component={Neptun}
....................